# Using Drupal7 custom entities in views

Tags: drupal-7, entity, drupal-views

I have created two custom entities using hook_entity_info in drupal 7.The entities is created for the given database tables.
I am able to create a view for each of the entities separately.But want to create a view of both entities together.The "relationship" option in view displays "no relationship available". And add fields option displays only the field of the secleted entity.

How do I relate both entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come with two solutions:

1)using relation ,relation end field,relation UI

2)using `hook_views_data_alter` example from commerce module:

```
         Function hook_views_data_alter(){ 
             // Expose the uid as a relationship to users.
             $data['users']['uc_orders'] = array(
                 'title' => t('Orders'),
                 'help' => t('Relate a user to the orders they have placed. This relationship will create one record for each order placed by the user.'),
                 'relationship' => array(
                     'base' => 'uc_orders',
                     'base field' => 'uid',
                     'relationship field' => 'uid',
                     'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
                     'label' => t('orders'),
                 ),
             );
         }
```